# Aritmética de apuntadores con arreglos en C++

Tags: c++, punteros

Tengo una pequeña duda de lo que sucede con este apuntador, el código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void func(int *, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, a[10]={1,2,3,2,5};
    func(a,4);              
    for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void func(int *b,int n)                                     
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {        
       if(b[i]==2) {
         b=b+1;                 
         b[i]=b[i]*2;       
       }                            
    }   
}
```

Precisamente en esta línea de código, no me queda muy claro qué es lo que pasa:

```
void func(int *b,int n)                                   
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {        
        if(b[i]==2) {
           b=b+1;                 
           b[i]=b[i]*2;     
        }                           
    }
}
```

En esta línea, cuando `i=1`, va a entrar al `if` porque el valor de `b[1]` es igual a `2`, pero, en este caso, el apuntador sigue apuntando al valor `0`, ¿cierto?, ¿o se ha ido moviendo?, porque cuando corro el programa, el primer y el segundo valor no cambian, pero el tercer valor que es `3` lo imprime como 6, cuando debería de imprimir 4, ¿cierto?.

En resumen, esta son las líneas que no me quedan muy claras:

```
b=b+1;
b[i]=b[i]*2;
```

¿Se desplaza y asigna el valor a `b[i]`?

Answer (score 3):

La clave es la línea `b = b + 1`, es aquí donde estás avanzando la posición del puntero al arreglo, por lo que en la siguiente línea cuando haces referencia `b[i]` ya no es el mismo elemento.  Para ilustrarlo:

[image: como avanza el puntero]

Cuando evaluaste `b[1]` era el elemento con valor 2, pero luego de modificar el puntero `b[1]` ahora hace referencia al elemento con valor 3 y es este el que estás duplicando.

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!! Excelente explicación. Muy agradecido amigo

Answer (score 1):

Cuando realizas la comparación `b[i]`, `b` sigue apuntado al `1`. No te equivocas.

`b[i]` es equivalente a `*(b + i)`, por tanto, se devuelve al valor de la posición i-ésima del vector, pero el valor de `b` no ha cambiado (`b + i` no implica `b += i`). Así que `b` sigue apuntado al `1` tras la comparación.

Luego, realizas la asignación `b = b + 1`, haciendo que `b` apunte al `2`.
Como `b` ahora apunta al `1`, `b[1]` (`i` aún vale 1), devolverá una referencia al tercer elemento, que multiplicas por `2`, obteniendo un `6`.

Comment: Muy buena explicación!